# Meaning of "open_file:" in c?

Tags: c

I was going through some code demonstrating error handling in file operations.
I can't understand what does **`open_file:`** mean and what does the colon after "open_file" signify ?

```
#include  <stdio.h>                                             

main()                                                          
{                                                               
   char  *filename;                                            
    FILE  *fp1, *fp2;                                           
    int   i, number;                                            

    fp1 = fopen("TEST", "w");                                   
    for(i = 10; i <= 100; i += 10)                              
       putw(i, fp1);                                            

    fclose(fp1);                                                

    printf("\nInput filename\n");                               

open_file:                           //What does this mean ?                                        
    scanf("%s", filename);                                      

    if((fp2 = fopen(filename,"r")) == NULL)                     
    {                                                           
       printf("Cannot open the file.\n");                       
       printf("Type filename again.\n\n");                      
       goto open_file;                                          
    }                                                           
    elsefor(i = 1; i <= 20; i++)                                    
    {  number = getw(fp2);                                      
       if(feof(fp2))                                            
       {                                                        
          printf("\nRan out of data.\n");                       
          break;                                                
       }                                                        
       else                                                     
          printf("%d\n", number);                               
    }                                                           

    fclose(fp2);                                                
}
```

Comment: It's a label - it's used by the line `goto open_file;` later on. Usually discouraged nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a goto label, used 7 lines below. It could be called sandeep: for all the compiler cares.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. Can a goto statement be used in any part of a program ?

Comment: It can, but I can't see many uses for goto these days. It tends to lead to very confusing and unstructured code. The only real valid use is to "emulate" the sort of behaviour a C++ destructor implements in C code, as you see it used in the Linux kernel. But there's usually better ways of doing that too!

Answer (score 1):

It's a label to which the `goto` a few lines later jumps..